# Not even close to a duplicate

Tags: discussion, duplicates

I see here [question about duplicates](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7036/rewording-a-questions-title-and-removing-the-duplicate-flag?rq=1) that it is OK to post here when one's question is falsely marked duplicate.
This is the case with my question [“I was late, and so I got fired.” Can we use two conjunctions in a row?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/438920/i-was-late-and-so-i-got-fired-can-we-use-two-conjunctions-in-a-row). The question linked as duplicate is regarding a specific aspect of the usage of "and so".
That other question is, word for word, *If "and so" connects predicates such that the second is the result of the first, do we need to repeat the same words in the second?* My question is whether it is actually incorrect to use "and so". I am still convinced that it is ultimately incorrect, while the other question is entirely based on the assumption that it is correct.

Whether it is proper English or not, no aspect of my question is even *hinted at* in the other.

I've edited my question to refute the duplicate claim, but I see it is 1 vote short of being deleted. Is there more I can do than posting about it here?
Thank you.

Comment: Duplicates aren't deleted and mistakes can be reversed just like other closures. There is more information about duplicates (and why they're not a bad thing!) in the help: https://english.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates That said, I don't think the "use of and so" is a good dupe target.

Comment: "No aspect...is even _hinted_ at...": both titles have '...and so...' which is the central part of your question. That's more than a hint.

Comment: Hang on a sec... we have always been told that duplicates are considered safe from deletion. Now I don't have the time to search the depths of meta but there are many posts about duplicates and how Stack Exchange doesn't think duplicates are "bad".

Comment: @ColleenV there are two votes in favour of deletion... they shouldn't even be there.

Comment: The two answers do mention "and so". I am too sleepy to think straight. Ciao.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Oh, thanks - I can't see the votes because I don't have the reputation. We get a lot of folks on ELL confusing "closed" with "deleted" and I thought this was another one of those cases.

Comment: @Mitch Fair enough, in the same way that two questions with titles mentioning "however" would include more than a hint of duplication.

Comment: @ChuckkHubbard I was just being a stickler. the content of the two questions is definitely different (rereading, I can barely tell what the other question is asking, but it's definitely not what you are asking).

Comment: @Mitch You caught me red-hyperboled! I was afraid of coming off as soft.